# Prestashop 1.6. How to check if product isPack in .tpl?

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to check in theme (front) **product.tpl** file (PS 1.6.1.4) ***if state*** if product is **Standard product** or **Pack of existing products**

`{if $product_type == Product::PTYPE_PACK}` not working....

I want to return **boolean**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
{if $packItems|@count > 0}
```

an example of using you can find it in product.tpl in the theme folder.
used in this way:

```
    {if $packItems|@count > 0}
            <div class="short_description_pack">
            <h3>{l s='Pack content'}</h3>
                    {foreach from=$packItems item=packItem}

                    <div class="pack_content">
                            {$packItem.pack_quantity} x <a href="{$link->getProductLink($packItem.id_product, $packItem.link_rewrite, $packItem.category)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$packItem.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a>
                            <p>{$packItem.description_short}</p>
                    </div>
                    {/foreach}
            </div>
    {/if}
```

Answer (score -1):

in addition, there is in a products object:

```
$product->id_pack_product_attribute = null 
$product->cache_is_pack = 0
```

for non-pack products